# my webpage displays nothing at all. No html,css or images,just keeps on loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, static

I am trying to create a website with django but when i use load static files , it only loads but displays nothing.Aside from that , it also displays "Not Found" for all the css ,images and javascript files .Any help will be appreciated. The project layout is below.

this is part of html code(full code is really long).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {%load static%}

    <title>LERAMIZ - Landing Page Template</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="LERAMIZ Landing Page Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="LERAMIZ, unica, creative, html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="{% static 'Mainapp/img/favicon.ico'%}" rel="shortcut icon"/>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Mainapp/css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Mainapp/css/font-awesome.min.css'%}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Mainapp/css/animate.css'%}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Mainapp/css/owl.carousel.css'%}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Mainapp/css/style.css'%}"/>


</head>


</html>
```

This is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
                  path('', views.index, name='index.html'),

              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


views.py


from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'Mainapp/index.html')

settings.py

import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Mainapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sur you have your static directory in your django project directory. you do not need to put that in your app directory. And if you haven't, or if you don't have a directory called mainapp inside of your static folder, then change the static tags to,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css'%}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css'%}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.css'%}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}"/>
```

like this for all

Comment: I have a Mainapp directory in my static directory and it is still displaying the "Not Found"errors and on my webpage it just keeps on loading without displaying anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it just cut out or you don't have a closing head tag and opening body tag?
2. In your urls.py. path('', views.index, name='index.html') just so you know it does not reference the index.html file it's just a internal point of reference so you can name it name="homepage" for instance.
3. Mainapp, let's assume your template stored at app/templates/Mainapp/ you'll have to change **'DIRS': [],** from templates to **'DIRS': ['templates'],**
4. You also don't have the allowed host set so you might want to do that.

Comment: yeah sorry it happened when i cut it out to reduce the amount of code.I have changed the templates in settings.py to 'DIRS': ['templates'],no difference.About the urls.py,I already know about that.But if Debug=True, what is need  to set allowed_host.And i also forgot to add {%load static%} in the code above but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it just cut out or you don't have a closing head tag and opening body tag?
2. In your urls.py. path('', views.index, name='index.html') just so you know it does not reference the index.html file it's just a internal point of reference so you can name it name="homepage" for instance.
3. Mainapp, let's assume your template stored at app/templates/Mainapp/ you'll have to change **'DIRS': [],** from templates to **'DIRS': ['templates'],**
4. You also don't have the allowed host set so you might want to do that.
5. Make sure you collect all the static files in location where you call {% static 'localtiontofile/staticfile' %}

Can you include the error messages you're getting when you try to run this on a locally?